# create class directly after a property field?

Tags: php, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [declare property as object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202995/declare-property-as-object)

in java you can create an object directly after the property field like this:

but it seems not working for php:

```
class Test {
    public $object = new Object();
}
```

you have to create it in the __construct() and assign it to the property?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

So no, you cant initialize it to an object. You'll have to do it in the constructor like you said