# PHP class and setting properties

Tags: php, class, singleton

So I ran into a problem while building a class in which I was unable to set the property of the class directly, and instead had to set it during construction. Here is an example of what I was trying to do.

```
class foo
{
    private $con = Db::init();

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    //continue class..
}
```

As you can see, I am just assigning a simple singleton PDO class to the property. This does not work, and I am forced to do the following.

```
class foo
{
    private $con;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->con = Db::init();
    }

    //continue class..
}
```

The first approach does not report any errors either. It just fails to continue execution. Any thoughts?

**edit**

The lack of errors may also be a Zen Cart thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [declare property as object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202995/declare-property-as-object)

Comment: *(related)* [Who needs Singletons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595964/who-needs-singletons/4596323#4596323)

Comment: Ha, I have read up on that article. I am straying away from it, however it is incredibly convenient in small projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening here is the class is a structure, and the structure is *compiled* before your PHP Fiel is executed, as in the compile time PHP Does not instantiate any dynamic data, you cannot use dynamic data.

For example:

```
$function = 'hello';
function $function(){}
```

Within the compile time the variable '$function' does not exists so it cannot be read, within your class PHP Has provided a function called `__construct` which is fired within run-time, meaning that the rest of the system's dynamic data is available.

```
class foo
{
    protected $bar;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bar = Db::Init();
    }
}
```

So the process is:

- Compile Time

  - Class foo
  - variable bar
  - function __construct
- Run Time

  - new foo found
  - internally create object
  - execute foo::__construct()
  - return foo

That's a simplified version of the process, there are some several ways to set objects to a class, you can do the regular approach as shown above

you can inject by doing:

```
public function __construct(Bar $bar)
{
    $this->bar = $bar;
}
```

you can create a base class and extend:

```
class DatabaseAccess
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = Db::Init();
    }
}
```

and then do:

```
class User extends DatabaseAccess
{
    public function getUser($id)
    {
         $this->db->fetchRow('users',$id);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Please see the class property docs at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

> ... this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

`Db::init()` must be evaluated at run time to determine the value to set the `private $con`, which conflicts with the compile time requirement of class properties.