# Can't initialize a PDO object in a class as a property

Tags: php, oop, class, pdo, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [declare property as object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202995/declare-property-as-object)

```
class core
{
 public $dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=newdbnaem;host=1.1.1.1:1111", "owner", "passwordlulz");
 function superman() {}
}
```

gives me a syntax error on the closing tag of the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only constant values can be used as initializers for class properties. Do it in the constructor:

```
class core {

    public $dbh = null;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=newdbnaem;host=1.1.1.1:1111", "owner", "passwordlulz");
    }

}
```

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php