# Using XML in PHP classes

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [declare property as object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202995/declare-property-as-object)
>   [Why don't PHP attributes allow functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960323/why-dont-php-attributes-allow-functions)

I'm trying to replicate the idea inspired by .NET's `web.config` by storing connection strings in an XML document.

but the problem is I keep getting an error everytime I try to load my XML file in the my class that would handle the database connectivity.

for example I have this XML markup:

**connections.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<connections>
    <connection name="MyConnection" 
                connectionstring="mysql:host=localhost;dbname=MyDatabase" 
                username="username" 
                password="password" />
</connections>
```

and the PHP class that would handle it.

**Connection.php**

```
<?php
    class Connection {
        // I keep getting errors here
        protected $xml = simplexml_load_file("connections.xml");

        // rest of my code here...
    }
?>
```

if it helps, here is the error message that is being thrown.

```
Parse error: syntax error, 
             unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in <path>\Connection.php on line 3
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot initialize a property with anything other than a constant. That is, you can do this:

```
protected $xml = "constant";
```

but *not* this:

```
protected $xml = something_a_function_returns();
```

So you need to move that code into the constructor:

```
class Connection {
    protected $xml;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->xml = simplexml_load_file("connections.xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: oh come on. thats a well known duplicate. dont answer it please.

Comment: @Gordon: For such easy questions I find it's easier to just answer on the spot. When/if someone CVs, I usually see that and add a vote too.

Comment: @Jon That is short sighted though. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91180/is-it-my-responsibility-to-search-for-duplicates-vote-to-close-before-answerin/105231#105231 why.

Comment: @Gordon: I understand and respect your opinion (and even partially agree). We disagree on how to come to grips with the fact that related q detection on SO is way off where it needs to be on a technical level; your proposal of fighting the issue with zealous perserverence towards the One True Answer is not practical enough for me, and my idea of "just give the customer a good answer since you can, next!" probably feels dirty to you. We both want to help people though (I could label your opinion "obsessive-compulsive" to go with my "short-sighted", but really both of those are unfair).

Comment: @Jon fair enough. I wouldnt call my opinion obsessive-compulsive though but rather disciplined ;)